# Prove $X/Y$ is a random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables then $X/Y$ is a random variable $(Y\neq 0)$.

I read this in some notes I found online from a university stating that $X+Y,XY,X/Y$ are all random variables. I know the proof for $X+Y$ which looks like,

$\forall r \in R,\ \exists q \in Q,  \{X<r,Y>c-r\} \subset \{X<q, Y>c-q\}$
$\cup_{r\in R} (\{X<r\}\cap\{Y>c-r\})\subset \cup_{q\in Q} (\{X<q\}\cap\{Y>c-q\})$
$\cup_{q\in Q} (\{X<q\}\cap\{Y>c-q\}) \subset \cup_{r\in R} (\{X<r\}\cap\{Y>c-r\})$

Is it possible the proof for $X/Y$ is similar? I cant seem to fix a constant ($r$).

Comment: Excellent nickname btw

Comment: What's the definition of $X/Y$ if not as a random variable given by $(X/Y)(\omega) = X(\omega)/Y(\omega)$? How is that "proof" that $X+Y$ is a random variable anything but a long list of unexplained symbols?

Comment: @Alex Pretty accurate as well

Comment: @homelessmathaddict sorry to hear that, hope things improve for you

Comment: @Christoph I've omitted the details, should probably add them in.

Comment: @Alex thank you, however im probably exaggerating because I consciously choose to l live in a caravan ;)

Comment: @homelessmathaddict please can you reference the proof of $X + Y$?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily prove a much more general statement using continuity and the fact that composition of measurable functions remain measurable.

From your attempt one can conclude that you are considering the canonical sigma topology on $\mathbb R$ and thus the Borel sigma algebra as canonical sigma algebra.

A simple exercise is now to show that addition, multiplication, etc are continuous functions $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. By definition of continuity, it is straightforward to see that continuous functions are measurable. Finally, use the fact that compositions of measurable functions are measurable (which is also easy to prove) to conclude that all elementary operations are measurable.

Comment: Thanks, could we assume, however, that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, and is that necessary for your first sentence to be true?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, ie functions $\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ which are $\mathcal F$-$\mathcal B$-measurable ($\mathcalB$ is the Borel sigma algebra). So can $X$ and $Y$ be continuous? No, the question makes no sense as there is no topology defined on $\Omega$.

Comment: Let $g$ be addition or multiplication function $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. As mentioned in my answer, it can easily be shown that $g$ is a continuous function and thus a $\mathcal B\otimes\mathcal B$-$\mathcal B$ measurable function. The function $g\circ(X,Y)$ is measurable as compositions of measurable functions are measurable

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$(\frac X Y <z)=(Y>0, X <zY) \cup (Y<0, X >zY)$$ $$ =\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb  Q} (Y>0, X <q<zY) \cup \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb Q} ((Y<0, X >r>zY).$$

[$(Y>0,X<q<zY)=(Y>0)\cap (X<q)\cap (zY>q)$ etc].

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is $\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb  Q} (Y>0, X <q<zY) \cup \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb Q} ((Y<0, X >r>zY) \in \mathcal{F}$ and since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra we could conclude the prood? Also, is it not just possible to set $Y>\frac{r}{c}$ using the method I posted above?

Comment: First question: YES. Second question: You have to be careful when you multiply an inequality by $Y$. If $Y <0$ the inequality gets reversed. That is why you have to split the set in to the portions $Y>0$ and $Y<0$.  @homelessmathaddict